# Bitonic Sorting with MPI

Tags: c, sorting, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm working on a project about the Parallel Bitonic Sorting using MPI and C to implement it. The program I developed works but it's not efficient since a simple QuickSort (sigh) beats it in terms of execution time. Maybe the problem is about the cost of communication but I don't get how to improve that, so here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "bs-util.h"
#include "quicksort.h"

#define TAG 1


/* Run this program knowing that:
 * 1) The number of cores must be a power of 2
 * 2) The length of the array to order must be a power of 2
 * 
 * Exec Example: mpirun -n 4 ./bs 1024 1024
 * */


void exchange(FILE *log, int i, int partner, int up);

int countTransfer = 0;

int *myArray, *partnerArray;
int currentPartner = -1;
int rank, size;
MPI_Status status;
int verbose = 0; //this var toggles on(1) or off(0) some useful prints for debugging purpose
int amount=0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *array;
    int i=0;
    int carry=0;
    int up=1;
    int count=0;

    struct timeval tim;

    FILE *log;

    char logName[15] = "log/";

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    /* Time meter */
    srand((double) time(NULL));
    gettimeofday(&tim, NULL);
    double t1=tim.tv_sec+(tim.tv_usec/1000000.0);

    snprintf(logName+4, 10, "%d",rank);
    log = fopen(logName,"w");

    printf("Hello world from process %d of %d.\n", rank, size);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    /* INPUT */

    if (rank==0) 
    {   
        if (argc==2) /* by file */
        {
            FILE *input = fopen(argv[1],"r");
            char line[20]; 
            count = 0;
            while(fgets(line,20,input) != NULL)
            {
                count++;
            }
            fclose(input);
            array = (int *)malloc(count*sizeof(int));
            input = fopen(argv[1],"r");
            i = 0;
            while(fgets(line,20,input) != NULL)
            {
                array[i] = atoi(line);
                i++;
            }
            fclose(input);
        }
        else
            if (argc==3) /* by command line */
            {
                count = atoi(argv[1]); 
                int max = atoi(argv[2]);
                array = (int *)malloc(count*sizeof(int));
                srand(time(NULL));
                for (i=0; i<count; i++)
                {
                    array[i] = rand()%max;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n\n ----------- ERRORE NEI PARAMETRI DI INPUT ----------- \n\n");
                return 1;
            }

        /* END OF THE INPUT */

        if (verbose){
            printf("Initial array:\n");
            for (i=0; i<count; i++)
            {
                printf("%d\t", array[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        /* Everyone wait eachother */
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        carry = count%size;
        amount = count/size + carry;
        printf("\nParametri: amount=%d carry=%d\n\n", amount, carry);
        up=1;
        int startIndex = amount;


        myArray = (int *)malloc(amount*sizeof(int));
        /* Buffer (partner) */
        partnerArray = (int *)malloc(amount*sizeof(int));

        for (i=0; i<amount; i++)
             myArray[i] = array[i];
        printf("Processo %d riceve amount=%d e up=%d\n", rank, amount, up);
        if (verbose){
            printf("Mia porzione ---> ");
            for (i=0; i<amount; i++)
            {
                printf("%d\t", myArray[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        /* Sending the big array's chunks */
        for (i=1; i<size; i++)
        {
            up = (i+1) % 2;
            MPI_Send(&up, 1, MPI_INT, i, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&amount, 1, MPI_INT, i, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&carry, 1, MPI_INT, i, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            MPI_Send(array+startIndex, amount-carry, MPI_INT, i, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            startIndex += amount-carry;
        }

        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
    } 
    else
    {
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        MPI_Recv(&up, 1, MPI_INT, 0, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&amount, 1, MPI_INT, 0, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&carry, 1, MPI_INT, 0, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        myArray = (int *)malloc(amount*sizeof(int));
        partnerArray = (int *)malloc(amount*sizeof(int)); /* Buffer (partner) */
        MPI_Recv(myArray, amount, MPI_INT, 0, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);


        /* Experimental padding: every chunck has the same amount of items. */
        for (i=amount-carry; i<amount; i++)
        {
            myArray[i] = 0;
        }

        printf("\n");
        printf("Processo %d riceve amount=%d e up=%d\n", rank, amount-carry, up);
        if (verbose){
            printf("Mia porzione ---> ");
            for (i=0; i<amount; i++)
            {
                printf("%d\t", myArray[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    /* CORE */

    /* Local Quicksort */
    int result = quickSort(&myArray[0], amount); //this function is written within src/quicksort.c
    if (verbose){
        if (result == 1)
            printf("Quick Sort: FAIL \n");
        else
        {
            printf("\nLa mia porzione ordinata (processo %d)\n", rank);
            for(i=0; i<amount; i++)
            {
                printf("%d ",myArray[i]);
            }
            printf ("\n");
        }
    }

    int j;

    for (up=8;up<=amount*size;up=2*up)
    {
        for (j=up>>1;j>0;j=j>>1)
        {
            for (i=0;i<amount*size;i++)
            {
                int partner=i^j;                
                if ((partner)>i)
                {   
                    exchange(log,i,partner,i&up);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    /* END OF THE CORE */

    if (rank!=0)
    {   
        MPI_Send(myArray, amount, MPI_INT, 0, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    gettimeofday(&tim, NULL);
    double t2=tim.tv_sec+(tim.tv_usec/1000000.0);
    if (rank==0)
    {
        myArray = (int *)realloc(myArray,sizeof(int)*amount*size);
        for (i=1; i<size; i++)
            MPI_Recv(myArray+i*amount, amount, MPI_INT, i, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        printf("\nTempo trascorso %6f\n", t2-t1);
        fprintf(log,"\n\n----------> Array Iniziale <----------\n");
        printArray(log,array,count);
        fprintf(log,"\n\n----------> Array Finale <----------\n");
        printArray(log,myArray+(carry*(size-1)),count);
        /*printArray(log,myArray,newAmount*size);*/

    }    
    fprintf(log,"Numero di chunk scambiati: %d\n",countTransfer);
    fclose(log);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}

void exchange(FILE *log, int i, int partner, int up)
{
    int rank_i = i/amount;
    int rank_partner = partner/amount;

    int offset_i = i%amount;
    int offset_partner = partner%amount;
    /*if (verbose)
        fprintf(log,"\nnewAmount = %d - Rank_i = %d - Rank_partner = %d - Offset_i = %d - Offset_partner = %d \n",amount,rank_i,rank_partner,offset_i,offset_partner);
    */

    if ((rank_i != rank) && (rank_partner != rank))
        return;

    if ((rank_i == rank) && (rank_partner == rank))
    {   
        if (((up==0) && (myArray[offset_i] > myArray[offset_partner])) || ((up!=0) && (myArray[offset_i] < myArray[offset_partner])))
        {
            int temp = myArray[offset_i];
            myArray[offset_i] = myArray[offset_partner];
            myArray[offset_partner] = temp;
        }
        return;
    }

    if (rank_i == rank && rank_partner != rank)
    {
        if (currentPartner != rank_partner)
        {
            MPI_Send(myArray, amount, MPI_INT, rank_partner, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Recv(partnerArray, amount, MPI_INT, rank_partner, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            currentPartner = rank_partner;
            countTransfer++;
        }
        if (((up==0) && (myArray[offset_i] > partnerArray[offset_partner])) || ((up!=0) && (myArray[offset_i] < partnerArray[offset_partner])))
            myArray[offset_i] = partnerArray[offset_partner];
        return;
    }

    if (rank_i != rank && rank_partner == rank)
    {
        if (currentPartner != rank_i)
        {
            MPI_Recv(partnerArray, amount, MPI_INT, rank_i, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Send(myArray, amount, MPI_INT, rank_i, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            currentPartner = rank_i;
            countTransfer++;
        }
        if (((up==0) && (partnerArray[offset_i] > myArray[offset_partner])) || ((up!=0) && (partnerArray[offset_i] < myArray[offset_partner])))
            myArray[offset_partner] = partnerArray[offset_i];
        return;
    }

}
```

And here's the Make file:

```
CC = mpicc
OPTIMIZE = 
CFLAGS = $(DEFINES) $(OPTIMIZE)
LFLAGS = -lm                
PROGS = ./bs
PROGS_SRC = src/bs-util.c src/bs.c src/quicksort.c


all:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) -o $(PROGS) $(PROGS_SRC)
```

Help would be very appreciated :)

References: http://goo.gl/nXt4p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that bitonic sort has time complexity of something like `N/P (log N)^2` compared to quicksort `N log N` (in serial version). This means that with `log N > P` (P ~ number of processors) should even the serial quicksort beat bitonic sort (I am not talking about multiplying with some factors depending on the implementation, neither the communication). Bitonic sort is for really parallel computers (it's pretty good on GPUs), not a grid of few PCs as you probably have.

Comment: Indeed, I'm working with 4, 8 or 16 processors while I'm trying to sort a few millions of items (academic purposes). Thanks for the useful explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Many sends/receives (as in exchange function) of small data chunks badly affect performance. More efficient is combining small chunks into one buffer and sending it.

Comment: @Flavio: all thanks on SO (StackOverflow) should be converted to upvotes and/or answer acceptance

Answer (score 1):

Um. I don't see you doing any collective communication other than barriers...

Comment: well what about the MPI_Send / MPI_Recv?

Comment: The awesome thing about MPI is that broadcast, alltoall, gather, scatter, reduce, scan, ... are optimized for you. Also, there is MPI file IO to speed up the file reading.  The basic framework for Batcher's sort would be to use MPI File IO to read in the data, sort it locally using C++'s std::sort, then start doing the merging.