# Can I reset MPI instance in c++?

Tags: c++, mpi

I wrote a sort algorithm with MPI. It is recursive mergesort, left child sorts half the array within the same process as the parent whereas right child gets a new process and receives half array from parent then sends the sorted array back to parent. Now I need to sort a bunch of integer files. Here is my current design:

```
int main()
{
  MPI_init();
  if(my_rank == 0)
  {
    foreach data file
    {
      sort_mpi(array);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    MPI_Recv(right_array...);
    sort_mpi(right_array);
    MPI_Finalize();
  }
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

With this code, the first file gets sorted and moves on to next file. However in the second interation of the for loop, it only stays in rank 0 and never goes to rank 1. It should be ideal if I can reset the MPI instance before going to the next file. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to reset the MPI - you need to have a point where all the instances are "freezing" in, and continuing only after all the instances got to this point...

Since it's homework - I won't tell you the method name, but I do Hope it helps.
Think about the design of the sort, and what state you need all the nodes to be in, when, and how to enforce it.

This example might be helpful (hoping it does not solve your homework, but just leading you in the right direction) [Bitonic Sorting with MPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433723/bitonic-sorting-with-mpi)

Comment: should I use MPI_Isend and MPI_Wait when I am sending sorted array back from right child to parent?

Comment: Have a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004068/mpi-process-synchronization

Comment: Looks like I need a MPI_Barrier. Should I add that right before it goes into any rank (before if rank ==0)?

Comment: So an MPI_Barrier says "I want nothing to continue - until all the threads are here". Think about the points in your code that you need computation to stop, or more data to be exchange across different nodes (this is really depends on the algorithm you use...  This is a good example you can learn from : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433723/bitonic-sorting-with-mpi

Comment: I just realize my problem here is not about getting all process to arrive at the same point. Since I am dealing with multiple data files (for loop on rank 0), every time one data file is sorted, all processes except rank 0 exits (MPI_Finalize). Therefore, when rank 0 starts the next data file, there is no process 1, 2, etc available. I can't seem to remove the MPI_Finalize for non-zero process, it will give me error. How do I handle finalizing non-zero processes?